# yaml.dump (snakeyaml) converting integer data to string data in java

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I have a yaml file with some data as shown in Figure 1:

[image: Figure 1].

I'm reading it into a `HashMap` using a yaml reader and doing some modifications and then writing it back to a new yaml file using a `yaml.dump()` (snakeyaml) in java. But this is converting some integer data (**paramvalue** is an int data in the original yaml) to string data as shown in this Figure 2:

[image: Figure 2].

Resulting yaml data after yaml.dump

```
field1:
   childfield1:
      datafield1:
         param1:
            childparam: 'paramvalue'
         param2:
            childparam2: 'paramvalue'
         param3:
            childparam3: 'paramvalue'
      datafield2: 'value2'
```

Expected yaml

```
field1:
   childfield1:
      datafield1:
         param1:
            childparam: paramvalue
         param2:
            childparam2: paramvalue
         param3:
            childparam3: paramvalue
      datafield2: 'value2'
```

Code:

```
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(); 
Map<String,Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) yaml.load("someYaml.yaml");
String output = yaml.dump(map);
```

Comment: Please edit your post to remove the images references and include the actual YAML (indent the cut and pasted YAML with four spaces using the `{}` button in the editor). While you are at it also remove the non-relevant begging (i.e. "Please help") it doesn't help making your question more clear, so it has no place in there. Use backquotes around code invocation references (`yaml.dump()`) to make them stand out as such

Comment: @Anthon i edited the question.

Comment: Much better, although you forgot to remove the begging. It looks like you read values in as strings, not as integers, can you provide the relevant code piece as well?

Comment: Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
 
 Map<String,Object> map = (Map<String, Object>)  yaml.load("someYaml.yaml");
 
 String output = yaml.dump(map);

Sorry I couldn't post the code properly.